# How to render a template from a folder which does not contain express.static?

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I have my loginController as

```js
var User = require('./../models/User.js');

var loginController = {};

loginController.match = function(req, res){

    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne({username : username, password : password})
    .then(function(user){
        if(user){
            res.render('profile',{
                title : 'Profile',
                user : user
            });
            /*return res.status(200).json({
                success : true,
                data : user
            });*/
        }
        else{
            return res.status(200).json({
                message : "Either username or password is wrong"
            });
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        return res.status(500).json({
            message : err
        })
    });
}

module.exports = loginController;
```

which runs as soon as i submit the login credintals.If on correct validation i want to render profile.handlebars and i am able to render it also but i am unable to consume the css which is using served using express.static and is present in a seperate file which is my app.js.

My app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');
var Path = require('path');

var routes = require('./routes.js');
var app = express();

/*View Engine*/
app.engine('handlebars',hbs({defaultLayout : 'layouts.handlebars', layoutsDir : __dirname + './../views/layouts'}));
app.set('views', Path.join(__dirname, './../views'));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

/*Serve Static files*/
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'./../public'));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/tournament', function(){
    console.log('connected to tournament..');
});

/*Template Routes*/
/*Login*/
app.get('/', function(req,res,next){
    res.render('login',{
        title : 'Login'
    });
})
/*Profile
app.get('/profile',function(req,res,next){
    res.render('profile',options)
});
*/


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret : "asdasdvbvc234234sdfsdf23213123", resave : false, saveUninitialized : true}));
app.use('/api', routes);

module.exports = app;
```

My profile.handlebars

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="float-right">
            Hello, {{user.username}}
            <button class="btn btn-md btn-danger">Logout</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the css loaded in the browser? Is the css loaded in your header.handlebars?

Answer (score 0):

try changing `app.use(express.static(__dirname+'./../public'));` to `app.use(express.static(Path.join(__dirname, './../public')));`

Comment: nothing suspicious in your directory tree!!! do as before and change `layoutsDir : __dirname + './../views/layouts'` to `layoutsDir : Path.join(__dirname, './../views/layouts')`

Comment: maybe you're not referring to your css the right way in index.html